# Dice-rolling program, not outputting what I need

Tags: java, loops

I'm writing a program that simulates the rolling of two 6-sided dice. The program will "reroll" the dice over and over until it achieves a 7. The program keeps track of how many rolls it took to get to 7. At the end of the code, the program will output an average which will be computed by (total number of rolls / n) "n" being the number of times the user chose to select the program.

The new issue I'm having is with the average number of rolls it takes to get a 7. I'm getting averages such as 0.125 rolls which obviously doesn't make any sense. I need to add in a new parameter I would guess but again, not sure.

```
  import java.util.*;
public class HW9 {
    public static void main(String args []) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = -1;
        do {
            System.out.println("Enter a number greater than 1.");
            n = s.nextInt();
        }
        while(n <= 1); 
        int total = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            int times = 0;
            int result = 0;
            while(result !=7) {
                result = (1 + ((int)(Math.random()* 6))) + (1 + ((int)(Math.random() * 6)));
                times++;
            }
            total = times;
        }
            System.out.println("Average: " + (double)total/n);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Java is not JavaScript. Aside from that potentially catastrophic error, you have a `while` loop which specifically tells the program to continue to ask you as long as you are inputting a number greater than `1`, rather than to stop asking you when that happens.

Comment: My mistake, didn't look closely when I added my tags. And what should I do to remedy this? I need the while loop I have to start the program(at least I think I do). Forgive me if this seems trivial but I have practically 0 experience with code and I'm just trying to pass the class I'm in.

Comment: Not going to tell you explicitly, but your code says "do the question while `n` is larger than `1`". You want "do the question *until* `n` is larger than `1`", or equivalently and more Java-ish-ly, "do the question while `n` is still *not* larger than `1`".

Comment: so I should go with while (n !> 1);     ?

Comment: That is not valid syntax. `!` is an operator that negates a boolean value, i.e. `true` or `false` (such as the result of a comparison); you can't negate another operator. But the idea is right. Also, "not greater" is the same as "less or equal". So you have two equally valid ways to rewrite it.

Comment: Ok thank you, it has stopped repeating itself but now the program will ask me for an integer and after inputting one and hitting enter, the program seems to be loading but never does anything. Thoughts on that?

Comment: Yup. You get a random number from `1` to `5` (dice go up to `6`, so that's an error too). Then you overwrite it with another number from `1` to `5`. A number from `1` to `5` (or even `1` to `6`, if you fix the first error) cannot ever be `7`. So your code works and works, the computer being too stupid to quit when the task is clearly impossible. :) If only the two die results could be combined, somehow...

Comment: You only ever use `total` from the last series. Maybe you meant `total += times`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking for a number greater than 1, but you are repeating your loop everytime the input is a number greater than 1.

```
do {
        System.out.println("Enter a number greater than 1.");
        n = s.nextInt();
    }
while(n > 1);
```

That `while(n > 1)` should be `while(n < 1)` or whatever you want to put in there.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is with your loop condition.

```
while(n > 1);
```

It repeats the statements inside your `do` block, while the condition is true. Inputting a number > 1 means the condition stays true, so it will continue to ask for input until you input a 0 or a negative number.

To fix it you would need to swap the condition statement, like so:
`while(n < 1)`